# Can managed packages be installed in parallel?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

Some of our Jenkins build install three largish managed packages sequentially taking about 30 minutes. I assume that these **installs cannot be done in parallel** instead cutting that time down to 10 minutes. (E.g. locks have to be applied in the platform during an install.)

Is this a correct assumption?

(I am aware of the org snaphot/shape mechanisms presently in pilot as a better way to go in the future.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Locks must be applied during an installation, which will prevent multiple packages from installing concurrently. You can make a package.xml file to install multiple packages in a single deployment, but those installs will still occur one at a time.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't want to be (stupidly) ignoring an easy way to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [idea to enable this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZnaUAF/install-multiple-appexchange-managed-packages-at-once) on the IdeaExchange. And I heard a rumor that this is on Salesforce's near-term roadmap.